# The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Basic'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Basic realm=""

Tags: web-services, wcf, wcf-binding

I am trying to access a Soap webservice (HTTP) which requires authentication.I am using WCF to consume the service. 
I am getting error Message as "The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Basic'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Basic realm="XXXXX"'."

However when I tried to send the authentication headers along with each request. I'm getting 401 errors when I attempt to do anything with the web service.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

This is what my code looks like:

```
 var myBinding = new BasicHttpBinding("exampleBinding");
    myBinding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;
    myBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
    myBinding.Security.Transport.ProxyCredentialType = HttpProxyCredentialType.Basic;
    EndpointAddress ea = new EndpointAddress("http://test.co.uk/webservices");

    var serviceClient = new ServicesClient(myBinding, ea);
    serviceClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "username";
    serviceClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "password";
    HttpRequestMessageProperty httpRequestProperty = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();

    httpRequestProperty.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Basic " +                   Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(serviceClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName + ":" + serviceClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password));

    httpRequestProperty.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ProxyAuthorization] =  "Basic " +             Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(serviceClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName + ":" + serviceClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password));

    using (OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope((IClientChannel)serviceClient.InnerChannel))
    {
      OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] =   httpRequestProperty;

      var response = serviceClient.DepartureBoard(request);
    }


Web config
-----------
   <bindings>
          <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="jpservicesBinding">
              <security mode="Transport">
                <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" proxyCredentialType="Basic" realm=""></transport>
                <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
              </security>
            </binding>
          </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
          <endpoint address="http://test.co.uk/webservices"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="exampleBinding"
            contract="RealTimePlanner.jservices" name="test" />
        </client>
```

Comment: The error message seems pretty straightforward.  You're trying to authenticate using "Basic," but the web service does not allow that.

Comment: I tried using all credential types and still throwing the same error .The problem is the service requires authentication header for every request but I am struggling how to do it through WCF to send authentication for every request